# addEdge with python gremling GLV - how to get syntax correct

Tags: python, gremlin, gremlinpython

The error:

```
TypeError: The child traversal of [['addV']] was not spawned anonymously - use the __ class rather than a TraversalSource to construct the child traversal
```

appears when trying to run the following code with python GLV

```py
a = g.addV()
b = g.addV()
print (type(a))
print (type(b))
g.addE('foo').from_(a).to_(b).next()
```

```py
#g.addE('knowing').to('b').iterate()
#g.addE("knowing").from_("a").to_("b").iterate()
a = g.addV().next()
b = g.addV().next()
print (a)
print (b)
#g.addE('foo').from(a).to(b).next()
g.V(a).addE('test').from_(V(b)).next()
```

works see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068278/1497139

**why is there still a .from_ necessary and not a .from?**

Comment: The calls to `addV()` need a terminal step like `next` otherwise they are going to be non-iterated traversals

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068278/1497139

Comment: Yes! hence you either need to iterate them, or make them anonymous `a = __.addV()`

Comment: `from` is a reserved word in Python. The standard TinkerPop convention is to us an underscore suffix in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion in the comments as an answer.

1. `from` is a reserved word in Python. The standard TinkerPop convention is to use an underscore suffix in such cases. So in this case, to avoid a reserved word conflict, the Gremlin Python driver uses `from_`.
2. In order to pass a `Vertex` from another query into `from` that other query needs to be terminated using `next`. So `a=g.V('1').next()` as an example.
3. In recent TinkerPop versions, use of `g` mid-traversal was removed in favor of using an anonymous traversal (`__.`). So, in this case, the `from_` step would be written as `from_(a)` , where `a` was previously defined as `a = __.V('1')`